# Validate IOptions<T> on start, Without using Bind to read from configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentvalidation, .net-8.0

SDK: .NET 8 RC4

I want to validate my options at the start. So I added this in my `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddOptionsWithValidateOnStart<SMTPOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SMTPOptions)))
    .ValidateFluently()
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

Works well and good. Because I have `FluentValidator` and everything is already wired up.
But now what I need is

1. Instead of letting it read configuration by it's own using `.Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SMTPOptions)))`
2. I want to pass an instance of `SMTPOptions` that I already created
3. Meaning, I want to source my `SMTPOptions` not from `appsettings.json` but in a custom way

So what can I do to replace Bind? I tried using `Options.Create<T>` and injected as Singleton but not working

Like this: This won't gets validated

```
var config = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SMTPOptions)).Get<SMTPOptions>();

builder.Services
    .AddSingleton(Options.Create(config))
    .AddOptionsWithValidateOnStart<SMTPOptions>()
    .ValidateFluently()
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

---

Other classes:

```cs
 public static class OptionsBuilderFluentValidationExtensions
 {
     public static OptionsBuilder<T> ValidateFluently<T>(this OptionsBuilder<T> optionsBuilder) where T : class
     {
         optionsBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<T>>(
             s => new FluentValidationOptions<T>(
                 optionsBuilder.Name, 
                 s.GetRequiredService<IValidator<T>>(),
                 s.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>()));
         return optionsBuilder;
     }
 }
```

```cs
 public class FluentValidationOptions<T> : IValidateOptions<T> where T : class
 {
     public string Name { get; }
     private readonly IValidator<T> validator;
     private readonly IHostEnvironment _env;


     public FluentValidationOptions(string name, IValidator<T> validator, IHostEnvironment Env)
     {
         Name = name;
         this.validator = validator;
         _env = Env;
     }

     public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string? name, T options)
     {
         if (Name is not null && Name != name)
         {
             return ValidateOptionsResult.Skip;
         }

         ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options, nameof(options));

         var validationResult = validator.Validate(options);
         if(validationResult.IsValid)
         {
             return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
         }

         var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         stringBuilder.Append($"Validation of '{typeof(T).Name}' failed. Please revalidate configuration files in '{_env.EnvironmentName}' environment.");
         stringBuilder.Append($"\n\nDETECTED ERRORS\n=============");
         validationResult.Errors.ForEach(error =>
         {
             stringBuilder.Append($"\n{error.PropertyName} - {error.ErrorMessage}");
         });

         return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(stringBuilder.ToString());
     }
 }
```

```cs
 public class OptionsValidator : AbstractValidator<SMTPOptions>
 {
     public OptionsValidator()
     {
         //If strings to be casted to Enums, This check is usefull
         RuleFor(x => x.ServerType)
             .IsEnumName(typeof(ServerType), caseSensitive: false);

         RuleFor(x => x.Port)
             .InclusiveBetween(0, 9)
             .WithMessage("Should be between 0-9");

         RuleFor(x => x.Server)
             .Empty()
             .WithMessage("Must be empty");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use `Configure`:

```
builder.Services
    .Configure<SMTPOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Port = config.Port;
        options.Server = config.Server;
        options.ServerType = config.ServerType;
    })
    .AddOptionsWithValidateOnStart<SMTPOptions>()
    .ValidateFluently()
    .ValidateOnStart();
```